# Microsoft Bot Framework, How to pass object from luis intent to prompt dialog yes/no

Tags: c#, bots

I am creating bot which will show results from bing search to users, and to ask users if the answer was accurate. If the answer is yes then to save that result. My question is how can i pass the result from search to prompt dialog or from flow?

Answer (score 0):

Without any context I'd say you have to use the bing API for searches:
http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search

Comment: yes, i am using bing search api, but the problem is after showing the results if the user wants to save the answer how to do that